# gradleのexpandについて

Tags: gradle

Javaで開発をしており、これまではantを使ってビルドをしていたのですが、
新たにgradleの導入を検討しております。

gradleでビルド自体は特に問題はないのですが、対象環境毎にリソースファイル内の値を
変更できないかと、こちらのページを参考に、expandを使用してやってみました。

http://d.hatena.ne.jp/bluepapa32/20110315/1300146980

結果、置換自体は成功したのですが、1点問題が出てきました。
置換対象のリソースファイル内には、改行コードやUnicodeを使用しているのですが、
置換コピーされたファイルを見ると、これらが全て除去された状態でした。
(例)
お知らせ\n
↓
お知らせ
expandを使うと、このようなファイルの置換はできないのでしょうか。
調べ方が悪いのか、いろいろ調べてみても原因や対処法などが見つからなかったので、
ご存知の方がいれば教えていただきたいと思います。

Comment: どこにどのように書いておいた改行コードがどの段階でどのように出力されて困っているのかわかりにくいので、事象が再現する最小限のサンプルコードがあるとアドバイスしやすいです。